# initialise jquery-isotope with angular2

Tags: angular, jquery-isotope

i need some help for angular2 issue. Currently i use jquery-isotope in my angular2 component. But i have problem to initialise jquery-isotope.
Could you help me please ?

**This is my code:**

```
Querygrid;
ngOnInit(): 
any {
 /* initiate isotope */
   this.jQuerygrid = jQuery('.draggable_media_list').isotope({
   itemSelector: 'div.dd',
   layoutMode: 'fitRows'
    });
 }
```

Comment: Hava you implemented the `OnInit` interface in your angular2 component?

Comment: yes i did, and i also add jquery. But the problem work only when use SetTimeout. But i would to avoid this.